# sql cross column calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql, clickhouse

Exists table:

```
currency1 | currency 2 | price
----------+------------+--------
usd       | eur        | 0.87
eur       | gbp        | 0.88
usd       | gbp        | 0.89
inr       | eur        | 0.90
usd       | inr        | 0.91
...
```

I need to find all options to find GBP for USD price where one currency is in-between. Example: usd-eur-gbp (by first two rows: buying EUR for USD, after that buying GBP for EUR).

1. Is there a name for this problem in general?
2. Is it possible to do with SQL (postgresql, click house)? (I want to rely on DBMS query optimizations)

Comment: What does your desired output for that sample data look like?

Comment: 0.87*0.88=0.7656

Answer (score 1):

The name of the problem "in general" is Self Join

```sql
    select a.currency1, a.currency2, b.currency2, a.price*b.price as price
    from table as a
    join table as b
    on a.currency2 = b.currency1
    where a.currency1 = 'usd'
      and b.currency2 = 'gbp'
```

That gives you all the variants to exchange usd to gbp over something. Result will have several rows or 0 rows (if there are no way to exchange).

Comment: EUR has been given for example. The part of this problem is to find any currency that can be used to buy the required (GBP) using the one we have (USD).

Comment: OK, that make your request more clear.  So the var 1 is more suitable:


`select a.currency1, a.currency2, b.currency2, a.price*b.price as price
from table as a
join table as b
on a.currency2 = b.currency1
where a.currency1 = 'usd'
  and b.currency2 = 'gbp'
order by price `


gives you all the variants to exchange usd to gbp over something. It can give you many rows or 0 rows (if there are no way to exchange).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need! 

Added aliases for columns so they don't overwrite each other (currency2).